# Express-session storing session in MongoDB but not setting a browser cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors, express-session

I'm using the express-session package to manage sessions in my Node.js application. I've configured it to use a MongoDB store to store sessions, and when a user logs in, the session data is successfully stored in the MongoDB database. However, I'm not seeing a session cookie in the browser.

**Here's a simplified version of my session configuration:**

```
const session = require('express-session')
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session)

const store = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: process.env.BD_URL,
    collection: 'sessions',
});

store.on('error', function (error) {
    console.error('Session store error:', error);
});

module.exports = (app) => {
    app.use(
        session({
            name: 'ziraat',
            secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
            resave: false,
            saveUninitialized: false,
            store: store,
     
            cookie: {
                maxAge: 3600000,
                secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
                sameSite:false,
                httpOnly: true
            }, 
        })
    );
};
```

**Here's a app.js code**

```
// Use the built-in middleware to parse incoming JSON data.
app.use(express.json());

// Enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to allow requests from different origins.
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

//------------ Configure Body Parser for Data ----------//

// Use the 'body-parser' middleware to parse JSON data from request bodies.
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//------------ Cookie Parser Configuration ------------//

// Use the 'cookie-parser' middleware to parse cookies from incoming requests.
app.use(cookieParser());


// Use the session to store the user data into session
session(app)


// Configure session serialization and deserialization
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
    done(err, user);
  });
});



//------------ Error Handling Middleware ------------//

// Use the 'errorHandlerMiddleware' to handle errors in the application.
app.use(errorHandlerMiddleware);


//------------ Define Routes ------------//

// Mount the 'productsRoute' middleware under the "/api/v1" path.
app.use("/api/v1", productsRoute);

// Mount the 'userRoutes' middleware under the "/api/v1" path.
app.use("/api/v1", userRoutes);

// Mount the authRoute middlware under the "/api/v1" path.
app.use("/api/v1/", authRoute)

// Export the configured Express application to be used elsewhere.
module.exports = app;
```

**Here is simplified version of the react app code to check authentication.**

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Check authentication status when the component mounts
  const checkAuthentication = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/auth/check-auth', {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      
      if (response.data.isAuthenticated) {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        setUserId(response.data.userId);
      } else {
        console.log(response);
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  checkAuthentication();
}, []);
```

Despite these configurations, I'm not seeing the session cookie being set in the browser, and as a result, response.data.isAuthenticated is always false.

I've also checked my backend route, and it correctly sets the session data and responds with isAuthenticated as true when accessed via Postman.

Comment: Why do you have `session(app)` when you're already adding session management using `app.use(session....)`?